# Image onload event not firing in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm creating an image preloader. It works fine in all browsers except Firefox (testing with Firefox 10.0). Basically the input is an array of images called `image_list`. These images are appended dynamically to the body of the document and a load callback is attached, which calls the function `update_progress`. The code is as follows:

```
$(image_list).each(function() {
      var x = $('<img />')
       .load(function() {update_progress(percent_loaded += step);})
       .attr('src', this)
       .appendTo('body')
       .css('display', 'none');
       .each(function() {
          if(this.complete)
             update_progress(percent_loaded += step);
      });
});
```

In Firefox, the load callback and `update_progress` are never called. Yet the exact same code works fine in chrome and all other browsers I've tested. Is there any way to detect when an image has loaded in Firefox?

Comment: Did you see the part at http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ which says "Caveats of the load event when used with images"? Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3877027/901048

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger yes I saw that reference in the api. I was just wondering if there was any way to reliably detect image load completion.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check to see whether the image has a height, by checking its height property.

```
if (the_image.height > 0) {
  // The image is already loaded (possibly cached)
}
```

If you have any cached images, etc, this should help you to get around that.